# Different forms of primal-dual second-order cone programs

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, convex-cone, dual-cone, second-order-cone-programming

I'm trying to understand the difference between the following two definitions of a SOCP (second-order cone program). The first way I've seen a primal-dual SOCP define is as follows:

The primal problem is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\min_x && c^T x \\
&\text{s.t.} && Ax=b \\
&&& x \in K
\end{aligned}
\tag{P1}
\end{equation}

and dual problem,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\max_y && b^T y \\
&\text{s.t.} && A^Ty + s = c \\
&&& s \in K^*
\end{aligned}
\tag{D1}
\end{equation}

where $K$ and $K^{*}$ are second-order cones. The second way I've seen an SOCP defined is as follows (as given under the "Linear Cone Programs" section of the following webpage: http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html):

The primal problem is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\min_x && c^T x \\
&\text{s.t.} && Ax=b \\
&&& Gx + s = h \\
&&& s \in K
\end{aligned}
\tag{P2}
\end{equation}

and the dual problem is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\max_{z,y} &&-h^{T}z-b^{T}y \\
&\text{s.t.} && G^{T}z+A^{T}y+c=0 \\
&&& z \in K^{*}
\end{aligned}
\tag{D2}
\end{equation}

How exactly can the above two primal-dual problems define the same thing? I'm rather confused, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's something wrong with your third problem above---it's missing an objective function.

Comment: Why do we only require $z \in K^*$ in D2? I would have thought there'd be three dual variables, $z, y, w$ where $w$ is the dual variable corresponding to $s \in K$, so that (if I'm not mistaken) the Lagrangian would be $\langle x, G^T z + A^T y + c, x \rangle + \langle s, z + w \rangle - z^T h - y^T b$?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at P1 and P2, consider taking $G = -I$ and $h=0$. Thus, the the second constraint in P2 gives
$$
-Ix + s = 0 \iff x = s
$$
so now we can formulate P2 as
\begin{align}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
&& c^T x \\
& \text{subject to} && Ax = b \\
&&& x \succeq_K 0
\end{align}

so P2 is a more general form of P1. I'm not sure if we can go the other way...